# How in laravel to make a deep HasManyThrough?

Tags: laravel

I created a relationship like this:

```
Type.City.Street.House.Apartment
```

In this relation, the apartment must depend on the House and on the Type at the same time, so result sql query must be like this:

```
select * from `apartments` where `apartments`.`house_id` in ('1', '2', '3') and `type_id` = '777'
```

The problem is that the HasManyThrough relationship only looks at a two of levels and it's not possible to get to the very first model with it.

Please, advise how this can be done?

My models definations:

```
class Type extends Model {
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
class City extends Model {
    public function street() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Street');
    }
}
class Street extends Model {
    public function house() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\House');
    }
}
class House extends Model {
    public function Apartment() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Apartment');
        //->where('type_id', '=' type.id) ?????
    }
}
class Apartment extends Model {
    public $fillable = ['house_id', 'type_id']
}
```

Comment: Post your model definitions

Answer (score 1):

I would add a mapping for `house_id` in `Apartment` model and sets bidirectional mappings among your models

```
class Apartment extends Model {
    public $fillable = ['house_id', 'type_id'];

    public function house() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\House', 'house_id');
    }
}

class Type extends Model {
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
class City extends Model {
    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type', 'type_id');
    }
    public function street() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Street');
    }
}
class Street extends Model {
    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'city_id');
    }
    public function house() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\House');
    }
}
class House extends Model {
    public function street() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Street', 'street_id');
    }
    public function Apartment() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Apartment');
        //->where('type_id', '=' type.id) ?????
    }
}
```

then you can query apartments as per your criteria like

```
Apartments::whereHas('house.street.city.type', function ($query) use ($type_id) {
                $query->where('id', '=', $type_id);
            })
          ->whereHas('house', function ($query) use ($house_ids) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $house_ids);
            });
```

And i guess there is no need for `type_id` in `Apartments` model

Comment: Thanks. Not the OP, but I didn't know about whereHas chaining like that. You just helped me simplify a bunch of code!

Answer (score 0):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Type extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function Apartment() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Apartment::class, [City::class, Street::class, House::class])
            ->where('apartments.type_id', $this->id);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with eager loading.

Comment: Wow! Great! I'll try this in the near future